# Colorbox as background for section headers in KOMA-class documents

Tags: layout, section-titles

I am using a KOMA-script class to generate my document (`scrartcl`). Now, I know that packages like `titlesec` are incompatible, it is recommended to use the options provided to customise the look of sectionheaders.

What I want is a colored background that starts from the edge of the page and has a length such that it fits the text but not much more.

After having a look at the KOMA manual, I stumbled accross an example adding `colorbox` to the section heading. I tried to modify this example for my use case, but now I hit a wall.

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm,left=1.0cm,right=2.3cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.0cm}

\makeatletter\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \hspace*{-2cm}\colorbox{gray}{%
            \parbox[t][.8cm][c]{.92\textwidth}{%
                \hspace*{1.85cm}\raggedsection\@hangfrom{\textcolor{white}{#3}}{\textcolor{white}{#4}}%
            }%
        }%
    }{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{This is a section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \section{This is a section with a g}
    
    \section{A section with a title that is longer than the others}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. How can I modify this such that the width of the `\parbox` is not fixed, but adapts to the length of the text length? (plus maybe .5cm)
2. Is there a more exact way of shifting the box to the border of the page other than `\hspace{}`, which is really just a bad approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach based on `tcolorbox` and `expl3`. The width of left margin is computed by `1in + \hoffset + \oddsidemargin` (see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins)). On two-sided documents, the calculation will be incorrect. Also, I am not sure if it is a common practice to use KOMA-script with `geometry`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm,left=1.0cm,right=2.3cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.0cm}

\tcbset{
    titlebox/.style={
        colframe=gray,
        colback=gray,
        arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
        top=1mm,
        bottom=1mm,
        left=\myleftmargin
    }
}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \myleftmargin {
    \dim_eval:n {1in + \hoffset + \oddsidemargin}
}
\cs_set:Npn \myfullwidth {
    \dim_eval:n {1in + \hoffset + \oddsidemargin + \textwidth}
}

\box_new:N \l_title_tmpa_hbox

\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{
        % determine the width of title
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_title_tmpa_hbox {
            \@hangfrom{\textcolor{white}{#3}}{\textcolor{white}{#4}}
        }
        % use different approach based on title width
        \dim_compare:nNnTF {\box_wd:N \l_title_tmpa_hbox} < {\textwidth} {
            % one line: use \tcbox
            \adjustbox{lap=-\myleftmargin}{
                \tcbox[titlebox]{\@hangfrom{\textcolor{white}{#3}}{\textcolor{white}{#4}}}
            }
        } {
            % multiple lines: use tcolorbox environment
            \adjustbox{lap=-\myleftmargin}{
                \begin{tcolorbox}[titlebox, width=\myfullwidth]
                    \@hangfrom{\textcolor{white}{#3}}{\textcolor{white}{#4}}
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }
        }

    }{
        \@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}%
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

    \section{This is a section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \section{This is a section with a g}
    
    \section{A section with a title that is longer than the others A section with a title that is longer than the others }
\end{document}
```